# How do I use Index() to create a 2D Variant Array of non adjacent columns greater than or equal to 65536 rows

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a 2D variant array from data in a worksheet.  The issue is The columns I want to use are not adjacent and the amount of elements exceeds 65,536. (the apparent limit for `Application.Index()` using an `Array()` as `Arg3`.  How should I proceed?

I have an answer to this question that works for me. I have read a great deal on this topic and I am curious if anyone else has had significant success with any other methods, because they are out there.

Comment: What's the deal with 65,536 rows? (2^16-1 is 65,535 BTW, i.e. 65,536 *already* overflows a `uint16`). Are you running 32-bit Excel? I'm looking at a successful `INDEX` result here, pulling an item at index 65538 out of a column with 1048576 rows, no problems. Also your answer looks like it's begging for upvotes, something that tends to attract the opposite reaction.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I sure would like some Rep :).  I will update the title to >=.  Did you pass an array as column criteria and have success?

Comment: What do you need the `Application.Index()` function for, as long as you are using VBA? Wouldn't `MyRange.Cells(x, y)` work for you?

Comment: @Gene I'm trying to fill an entire array and using index on entire columns.  Not just a single cell.  You suggest a for loop through cells?  Great.  Post up an answer.  I hope to time all the responses to find the fastest.

Comment: @Joshua: No, I am not suggesting looping through cells. Apparently I misunderstood you reference to the Index()? If you are you using it to get to you data the Range.Cells works, or if you are trying to use it to collect your data then how would you even do that?

Comment: @Gene Read the answer I posted.  I said I had one.

Answer (score 0):

### One Very Fast Solution:  .Evaluate()

`Application.Index([Range/Array],[Row],[Column])` is an extremely useful function.

## Answer:

```
Dim arr as Variant 'This is the array you want to create.
Dim varRows as Variant 'This will hold the rows want to index
Dim LastRow as Long 'This is the last row of data you are needing

LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row  'set the last row

varRows = Evaluate("row(1:" & LastRow & ")") 'Evaluate is the make or break here. You can modify your start row as well by changing the 1.

arr = Application.Index(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells, varRows, Array(1, 3, 5)) 'You can set your array to be any columns you want.

'arr will now be a 2D array arr(1 to varRows, 1 to 3) in this example.
```

This method is so very fast it is dumb.  It beats the pants off of a For Loop.
I passed a Range in this example but an array can also be passed if you need to Slice out 1 or more columns into a new array

## Slice columns from an existing array Of any Type!:

This creates a Variant array and variants are so easy to get and return to the sheet.

```
Dim arr as Variant 'This is the array you want to create.
Dim SmallerArr as Variant 'the new array
Dim varRows as Variant 'This will hold the rows want to index
Dim LastRow as Long 'This is the last row of data you are needing

LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row  'set the last row

varRows = Evaluate("row(1:" & LastRow & ")") 'Evaluate is the make or break here. You can modify your start row as well by changing the 1.

arr = Application.Index(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells, varRows, Array(1, 3, 5)) 'You can set your array to be any columns you want.

'read a single column into a new variant array
SmallerArr = Application.Index(arr, varRows, 1) 'You can set your array to be any columns you want.

'read multiple columns into a new variant array
SamllerArr = Application.Index(arr, varRows, Array(1, 2)) 'The columns must exist in arr or you will get an error.

Dim lngArr(1 To 100000, 1 To 3) As Long 'create 2D array of type long
'Fill array
For h = 1 To 3
    For j = 1 To 100000
        lngArr(j, h) = j * h
    Next j
Next h

SamllerArr = Application.Index(lngArr, varRows, Array(1, 2)) 'The columns must
'we just turned a long array into a variant array!
'we can read it to the sheet without a For loop!
```

## Read columns back to the sheet:

```
Dim arr as Variant 'This is the array you want to create.
Dim SmallerArr as Variant 'the new array
Dim varRows as Variant 'This will hold the rows want to index
Dim LastRow as Long 'This is the last row of data you are needing

LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row  'set the last row

varRows = Evaluate("row(1:" & LastRow & ")") 'Evaluate is the make or break here. You can modify your start row as well by changing the 1.

arr = Application.Index(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells, varRows, Array(1, 3, 5)) 'You can set your array to be any columns you want.

'Read 1 column to the sheet
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A" & LastRow) = Application.Index(arr, varRows, 1) ' cange the range and column accordingly

'Read multiple columns to the sheet
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:B" & LastRow) = Application.Index(arr, varRows, Array(1, 2))
```

## Notes:

1)  `varRows` can be modified to accept any position of elements.

2)  In Excel 2013 at least, when using `Index()` without passing arrays as arguments for row/column, there does not appear to be any row limitations.

3A)  All arrays created this way are 2D.  Even if they are 1 column they are still 1 wide.

3B)  `Application.Transpose()` has row limitations as well just in case you were trying it...

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure how to interpret the question but here is a method (two variations) of doing what I guess is asked for. This can be expanded/automated/adjusted as desired.

```
Sub ForJoshua1()
' Say, you want 2 columns: "B:B", "H:H"
    Dim vX(1 To 2) As Variant
    vX(1) = Range("B:B")
    vX(2) = Range("H:H")
End Sub

Sub ForJoshua2()
' Say, you want 2 columns: 2, 8
    Dim vX(1 To 2) As Variant
    vX(1) = Sheet1.Columns(2)
    vX(2) = Sheet1.Columns(8)
End Sub
```

If you have an "a" in the cell "B12", for example, then
   `vX(1)(12,1)` would equal "a"

Comment: A 3D array.  Neat